# Which Stack Exchange site is for asking/discussing about system flows?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm developing systems I really don't have much background on. I do research, but I have some questions I'd like to ask that I can't find the answers to. I'm talking about system flows here for like [POS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_sale) systems or accounting systems. "How is a process supposed to happen?", "Am I providing all the basic information needed?", etc.

**Note**: I'm talking about computer system development.

Comment: SE cannot get involved with system analysis and architectural design.  There is a 30k limit on questions that would prevent the posting of comprehensive requirement specifications, even if somebody was inclined to do so much detailed work for no wage. I can't see how such issues could be handled in a Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) can help......

Comment: Sorry but that's really far from what i'm looking for. I'm talking about computer system development here.

Comment: @crimson589 Then you should add that information to your question.